# Pycharm lack of Intelisense for nested class properties

Tags: python, kubernetes, pycharm, kubernetes-python-client

I'm using kubernate client to get the nodes list like this way.

```
obj = KubeApiHelper("default")
nodeList = obj.get_nodes_list()
for node in nodeList.items:
    print node.**status.conditions**
```

the line I bold I lack of Intelisense helper from IDE.
I want to iterate through my nodes and pick up some nested properties about status.

This is the view on intelisense window.
[image]

Is there a possibility to make pycharm aware of nested class properties (aka intelisense) . As you can see in the picture I have no help from intelisense when browsing through node status object. I used to work with visual studio and c# which such operation for ide was not an issue.

Comment: What is the question? Thx.

Comment: I edited my post. In short my question is why pycharm do not help me with node.(a lot of properties here). Probably I'm missing some general knowledge.

Comment: I rephrase my question and get the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439803/missing-intellisense-autocompletition-in-for-loop

Comment: Great, good to hear!